# Review request: Thread safe queue (parallel push pop)

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

Here is an implementation of a thread safe queue. The push and pop won't block each other. However, pop will wait until an item is pushed, if the queue is empty. Multiple producers and consumers can use the queue. Please tell me if you see any problems.

Update: Edited as per answers 1)Resolved the issue of "Queue Full" situation. 2) There is `BlockingCollection<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` in .NET4. So there is no need to reinvent the wheel(for .NET4)

```
public class CustomQueue<T> where T: class
{
    class Node
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Value = null;
            NextNode = null;
        }

        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
            NextNode = null;
        }

        public T Value;
        public Node NextNode;
    }

    object PushLocker = new object();
    object PopLocker = new object();
    Semaphore QueueSemaphore;
    volatile int PushIncrement;
    volatile int PopIncrement;
    int MaxItems;
    Node FirstNode;
    Node LastNode;

    public CustomQueue(int maxItems)
    {
        QueueSemaphore = new Semaphore(0, maxItems);
        MaxItems = maxItems;
        FirstNode = LastNode = new Node();
        PushIncrement = 0;
        PopIncrement = 0;
    }

    public int Size()
    {
        return PushIncrement - PopIncrement;
    }

    public bool Push(T value)
    {
        lock(PushLocker)
        {
            if((Size()) >= MaxItems)
            {
                lock(PopLocker)
                {
                    PushIncrement = PushIncrement - PopIncrement;
                    PopIncrement = 0;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            Node newNode = new Node(value);                
            LastNode.NextNode = newNode;
            LastNode = newNode;
            PushIncrement++;
            QueueSemaphore.Release();
            return true;
        }            
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        QueueSemaphore.WaitOne();
        lock(PopLocker)
        {
            Node tempFirst = FirstNode;
            Node tempNext = FirstNode.NextNode;
            T value = tempNext.Value;
            tempNext.Value = null;
            FirstNode = tempNext;
            PopIncrement++;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to minimize the amount of work done inside the locks. Some of those statements can safely be moved before the lock.

Comment: why do not use ConcurrentQueue? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: @saeedalg-Concurrent queue push and pop won't block each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a good implementation at a glance. Using different locks is always a red flag to me so I took a good hard look at *some* of the edge cases involving simultaneously calls to `Pop` and `Push` and it appears safe. I suspect you probably educated yourself on the linked list implemenation of a blocking queue huh? The reason why this is safe is because you only ever reference `LastNode` from `Push` and `FirstNode` from `Pop` otherwise the whole trick would fall apart.

The only thing that is sticking out at me right now is that when you try to release a count from a `Semaphore` it will throw an exception if it is already full so you might want to guard against that.<sup>1</sup> Otherwise you will end up with extra nodes in the linked list and the queue will 1) have more than the maximum number of items and 2) it will get live-locked.

**Update:**

I gave this some more thought. That `Release` call in the `Push` method is going to be *very* problematic. I see only one possible solution. Remove the `maxItems` parameter from the constructor and allow the semaphore to count up to `Int.MaxValue`. Otherwise, you are going to have to radically change your approach resulting in an implementation that is no where close to what you currently have.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I think you will find that this will be more difficult than what you might immediately realize.</sub>

Comment: +1, but couldn't he just use a second Semaphore that's initialized with `maxItems`, and `Push` waits for it and `Pop` releases it? Then Push would block, too, if the queue is full. (Didn't think that through to the end, though)

Comment: that is spot on! I edited the post with a solution to the problem by checking the size before each push.

Comment: @Jimmy: Hmm...I am going to have to ponder your modification for awhile. The fact that `PopIncrement` is not synchronized while simultaneous reads and writes are occurring is a red flag, but that does not necessary mean anything is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this for self-education, great - otherwise [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) or [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) are good alternatives.

One problem I do see here is that there is no way to interrupt `Pop` once it starts - it assumes an object is waiting when it awakens.  How would you clear this down on termination?  A `TryPop` that returns `true` (with an element) or `false` (if no data) might be better, then you could signal waiting threads to shut down cleanly once the queue is drained.

Comment: It is legal. That's one of the central differences between a semaphore and a mutex - a semaphore can be acquired/released on different threads, a mutex has to be released by the thread that acquired it.

Comment: @nikie - thanks - I thought that was the case, but the Microsoft docs are very slanted towards suggesting threads call `WaitOne` and then `Release`...

Comment: You're right, the docs are far from clear. But I definitely read that in Joe Duffy's "Concurrent Programming on Windows" - IIRC, a blocking queue was actually one of the examples for using a semaphore.

Comment: @nikie - yes, I took that part out of my answer now, which makes it a bit 'me too' I'm afraid.

Comment: the rational behind "trypop"-agreed. However, I am not writing it now as I expect the consumer to wait for an item in the queue.

Answer (score 3):

`1.` Consider adding a second Node constructor:

```
        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
```

then your client code:

```
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.Value = value;
```

can treat the value as an invariant:

```
            Node newNode = new Node(value);
```

`2.` Then make your public fields:

```
        public T Value;
        public Node NextNode;
```

into auto properties:

```
        public T Value { get; private set; };
        public Node NextNode { get; set; };
```

So you can abstract the usage from the implementation and add validation, other processing, etc. after the fact with minimal disruption to client code.

Comment: As the fields are private(hence not part of interface) does it makes sense to change it to property??

Comment: I'll still say it makes for good design to do so.  The JIT process may even turn it into a direct field access, so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

See this if you have .NET 4: [Blocking Collection and the Producer-Consumer Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm a fan of immutable objects, here's an alternative to my earlier answer that I would consider a bit cleaner:

```
public sealed class CustomQueue<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly object pushLocker = new object();
    private readonly object popLocker = new object();
    private readonly Semaphore queueSemaphore;
    private readonly int maxItems;
    private volatile int pushIncrement;
    private volatile int popIncrement;
    private Node firstNode = new Node();
    private Node lastNode;

    public CustomQueue(int maxItems)
    {
        this.maxItems = maxItems;
        this.lastNode = this.firstNode;
        this.queueSemaphore = new Semaphore(0, this.maxItems);
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pushIncrement - this.popIncrement;
        }
    }

    public bool Push(T value)
    {
        lock (this.pushLocker)
        {
            if (this.Size >= this.maxItems)
            {
                lock (this.popLocker)
                {
                    this.pushIncrement = this.pushIncrement - this.popIncrement;
                    this.popIncrement = 0;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            Node newNode = new Node(value, this.lastNode.NextNode);

            this.lastNode = new Node(this.lastNode.Value, newNode);
            this.firstNode = new Node(null, newNode);
            this.pushIncrement++;
            this.queueSemaphore.Release();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        this.queueSemaphore.WaitOne();
        lock (this.popLocker)
        {
            Node tempNext = this.firstNode.NextNode;
            T value = tempNext.Value;

            this.firstNode = tempNext;
            this.popIncrement++;
            return value;
        }
    }

    private sealed class Node
    {
        private readonly T value;

        private readonly Node nextNode;

        public Node()
        {
        }

        public Node(T value, Node nextNode)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.value;
            }
        }

        public Node NextNode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nextNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this version probably won't work as you are changing the lastnode and firstnode in push. The whole solution works because push access only lastnode and pop access only first node(as Brian's post explains). Also, by making the objects immutable what is the benefit in this solution? Isn't it messing with the "linked list" concept?

Comment: I suggest reading Eric Lippert's articles (like 11 of them) on immutability and the benefits they have.  In particular, I'd recommend reading about his immutable stack: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx